# Cannot Run a cdk list due to package error

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, aws-cdk

I am having an issue with the aws-cdk and it seems to be related to typescript or npm packages but I can't be sure. Here is my error:

```
Cannot find module 'typescript'
Require stack:
- /home/aroe/zivaro/cybersecurityengineering/securityBaseline/node_modules/ts-node/dist/index.js
- /home/aroe/zivaro/cybersecurityengineering/securityBaseline/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js
```

This happened after updating specific packages from aws-cdk. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please share what exactly you have updated? After which you are getting this error.

Comment: Looks like it's not finding `typescript`. Is it installed? Try installing it globally - `npm install -g typescript` or if you use yarn - `yarn global add typescript`